# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[]

Tags: vb.net, wcf, ienumerable

Currently I am receiving the error unable to cast table to `IEnumerable`, which I am finding very perplexing as at no time am I specifying a table.

I will explain step by step what is being done and please do point out where I went wrong.

**DAL:**

```
Public Function GetCategories(ByVal DB As WholeSaleDataDataContext, Optional CategoryID? As Integer = Nothing) As IEnumerable(Of Category)
    If CategoryID Is Nothing Then
        Return DB.Categories.AsEnumerable()
    Else
        Return DB.Categories.Where(Function(Cat) Cat.CategoryID.Equals(CategoryID)).AsEnumerable
    End If    
End Function
```

**WCF:**

```
<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(WholeSalesDAL.Category))>
Public Class Category2

End Class

Public Function GetCategory() As IEnumerable(Of Category2) Implements IWholeSaleData.GetCategory
    Return WholeSalesDAL.GetCategories(_DB).AsEnumerable
End Function
```

**Website:**

```
Private WholeSaleServices As WholeSaleService.WholeSaleDataClient

Public Sub New()
    WholeSaleServices = New WholeSaleService.WholeSaleDataClient("BasicHttpBinding_IWholeSaleData", "http://localhost:16722/WholeSaleService.svc")
    GetCategories()    
End Sub

Public Sub GetCategories()
    Dim z = WholeSaleServices.GetCategory
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Your `WCF` code snippet shows you are returning the result of the `GetCategories` from the DAL, but the signature of this function returns an `IEnumerable(Of Category2)`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @ataravati what syntax errors are there the code itself works I am making a conversion mistake somewhere

Comment: @J.Hudler no as can be seen in the datacontact it is a knowntype

Comment: @Enzero, sorry! You're right.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

**EDIT**: #1 explained...

1) In your WCF section, `WholeSalesDAL.GetCategories(_DB)` is `IEnumerable(Of Category)`, but your function is supposed to return `` `IEnumerable(Of Category2) ``.  I don't see how that type conversion is being done.

2) I believe you are using `AsEnumerable` unnecessarily, and that is probably what is causing the exception.  Do you know if you need to call `AsEnumerable` in either spot you have it?  I would try removing it.

Comment: @psuedocoder the asenumerable in itself is not wrong, the type conversion is done through the datacontract known type

Comment: @Enzero I see, thank you.  I would still try removing AsEnumerable unless it's necessary for some reason.

Comment: @psuedocoder removed asenumerable and still have same problem